# QGIS Export Vector Shapefile attribute table metadata

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, metadata

In QGIS, I am looking for a way to export shapefile "attribute table metadata" (data about the the data, i.e. Id, Name, Alias, Type, Type Name, Length, Precision, Comment) not the shapefile metadata (Extent information, etc.) I would think that this would be something that would be identified as a "data dictionary" or "list of field properties and requirements."

There are numerous way to export the content (data itself), but I am seeking to export the details about that data (metadata).

Hopefully, the pictures help to clarify the two different QGIS layer properties panels:

The first being the information that I would like to somehow extract (Fields)

The second being the information that I do NOT need extracted (Metadata.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: A pyqgis script would be an option for you?